# Mutability and Summing Ruby Hash Values

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm attempting to sum values from a hash, and I'm running into some unexpected (to me) behavior. Below is code which reproduces the behavior.

```
records = [
  { "id" => 5062311, "period" => "May 27, 2018", "items" => 2, "compliant_items" => 2 },
  { "id" => 5062311, "period" => "May 20, 2018", "items" => 3, "compliant_items" => 1 },
  { "id" => 5062311, "period" => "May 13, 2018", "items" => 7, "compliant_items" => 7 },
  { "id" => 5062311, "period" => "May 13, 2018", "items" => 8, "compliant_items" => 7 },
  { "id" => 5062311, "period" => "Jun 03, 2018", "items" => 6, "compliant_items" => 6 }
]
```

Create Output Hash

```
items  =  records.flat_map { |item| item["id"] }.uniq
weeks  =  records.flat_map { |item| item["period"] }.uniq
temp   =  items.each_with_object({}) { |item, hash| hash[item] = weeks.product(["total" => 0, "compliant" => 0]).to_h }
```

Output for "temp" is as follows...

```
{
  5062311=>{
   "May 27, 2018"=>{"total"=>0, "compliant"=>0},
   "May 20, 2018"=>{"total"=>0, "compliant"=>0}, 
   "May 13, 2018"=>{"total"=>0, "compliant"=>0}, 
   "Jun 03, 2018"=>{"total"=>0, "compliant"=>0}
  }
}
```

Now if I attempt to modify a particular key's value, every other key is also updated. For example, the following:

```
temp[5062311]["May 20, 2018"]["total"] += 5
```

yields...

```
{
  5062311=>{
   "May 27, 2018"=>{"total"=>5, "compliant"=>0},
   "May 20, 2018"=>{"total"=>5, "compliant"=>0}, 
   "May 13, 2018"=>{"total"=>5, "compliant"=>0}, 
   "Jun 03, 2018"=>{"total"=>5, "compliant"=>0}
  }
}
```

I would expect that only the May 20th record to be updated, and all other values to remain 0. I'm not sure how to rewrite this to get around this behavior. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is basically the following.

```
a = ["dog", "cat"]
b = [:d1, :d2] 
c = { :f=>1 }

h = a.each_with_object({}) { |pet, h| h[pet] = b.product([c]).to_h }
  #=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}},
  #    "cat"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}}
```

Now let's change the value of `:f` in one of the hashes `{ :f=>1 }`

```
h["cat"][:d2][:f] = 2
```

and then observe the new value of `h`.

```
h #=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>{:f=>2}, :d2=>{:f=>2}},
  #    "cat"=>{:d1=>{:f=>2}, :d2=>{:f=>2}}}
```

You were expecting `h` to equal:

```
#=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}},
#    "cat"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>2}}}
```

To see why we get this result, replace each hash `{ :f=>1 }` with its `object_id`.

```
a.each { |aa| d.each { |bb| h[aa][bb] = h[aa][bb].object_id } }
h #=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>36327481, :d2=>36327481},
  #    "cat"=>{:d1=>36327481, :d2=>36327481}}
```

As you see all four of these hashes are the same object. It should therefore be expected that if the object is changed the change will appear wherever the hash appears.

Here is one way to fix the problem.

```
h = a.each_with_object({}) { |pet, h| h[pet] = b.map { |d| [d, c.dup] }.to_h }
  #=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}},
  #    "cat"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}}}

h["cat"][:d2][:f] = 2
  #=> 2
h #=> {"dog"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>1}},
  #    "cat"=>{:d1=>{:f=>1}, :d2=>{:f=>2}}}
```

A word of warning: if `{ :f=>1 }` contained nested elements, such as `{ :f=>{ :g=>1 } }` we could not simply dup it (because a change to `{ :g=>1 }` would affect all the hashes); instead we would require a [deep copy](https://www.thoughtco.com/making-deep-copies-in-ruby-2907749).